# How do I display a NOAA generated XML file on a 'blogger' website

Tags: xml, blogger, weather, noaa

I want to display the following xml file on my 'blogger' website. I can query the data I want from the NOAA but I am stuck on how to write a script to transform it to html.

Here is the xml file generated form the NOAA:
http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=CYVR&hoursBeforeNow=3&fields=raw_text,flight_category

The 'blogger' page looks like this:
http://acweather.blogspot.com/search/label/CYVR%20-%20Vancouver

What I want to do is remove the current 'iframe' displaying METAR and TAF data from the NOAA and replace it with the XML data, displayed using a table in HTML.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never...

The problem is that blogger sites are pretty locked down: I believe they've stamped out any javascript injection techniques one could use. Well, you could use a [Blogger Gadget](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger), pull the data from wherever you're hosting the gadget (to sidestep XSS with javascript), but by that time you might as well just pull/transform the XML file from wherever you're hosting (ex. [Google App engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)) and serve up the data in the same iframe (skipping the formalization of a gadget), except just in an HTML table.

On the other hand, it looks like you transitioned to google sites, so this is only for posterity.